# Can't add properties via Javascript to DOM object received via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-9, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting a SVG DOM object (`<svg> ... </svg>`) by making a GET XMLHttpRequest via JavaScript. I need to add some properties to the received object, like so:

```
svgObject.prop = 5
```

where `prop` should be created by JavaScript as a new property of the object.

For some reason, this is not possible in IE9 and I get the error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

However, this works in Firefox and IE10. Has anybody encountered this behavior? Does anybody know how to go around it in IE9?

Comment: have you tried creating the property before, then populating it? like `var svgObject = { prop:'' };` then later `svgObject.prop = 5`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. My svgObject will be returned by an XMLHttRequest, so I'm not creating it myself.

Comment: Ah, try `svgObject["prop"] = 5`, IE could be seeing `.prop` as a keyword and failing because its the wrong context

Comment: Thank you, no success though. Anyway, "prop" is just a name I made up, any other name would behave the same. Actually in our project we have a bunch of properties we need to set up for svgObject and they all fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Internet Explorer 10, the object returned by `XMLHttpRequest` was [not a native object](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?476028-Adding-property-to-XMLHttpRequest-Object-in-IE), therefore, the object didn't allow expanded properties. Microsoft [fixed this in Internet Explorer 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and made `XMLHttpRequest` return a native object to make their implementation more compatible with other browsers.

Comment: So what would his would his work around be? I would use jQuery or similar library to do the request. That way it would at least be cross-browser compatible, using either `$.ajax();` or `$.getJSON();`?